# How do I do a cross-platform backup/restore of a DB2 database?

Tags: backup, restore, db2

I need to dump a couple of databases from DB2 for Mac and DB2 for Linux and then import the databases to DB2 for Windows.  Unfortunately, when I try the standard backup and restore I get the following error:

> SQL2570N  An attempt to restore on target OS "NT-32" from a backup created on
>   source OS "?" failed due to the incompatability of operating systems or an
>   incorrect specification of the restore command.  Reason-code: "1".

I've seen references to DB2 needing an IXF dump and import, but I can't find any solid information about how to do this without dozens of other steps.

Any hints on how to do this in the least painful manner?

Comment: duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/97282/restore-db2-database

Comment: You mean that question is a dupe of this one.  This one was asked first.

Comment: You are right. So for the records, have a look at the duplicate of this question for the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not possible to say a comment is an answer I'm going to post it here:

[Restore DB2 database](https://serverfault.com/questions/97282/restore-db2-database)

That question poses a similar problem and contains the solution.

Answer (score -1):

No way could you restore a database from a backed up image in another OS. The best way, as I am aware of, to do this is to create a barebone db in the target, set up federated server against the source db, create nicknames against tables then do a cursor/export load.

Comment: There is a way. It is not straightforward, but officially documented by IBM. See http://serverfault.com/questions/97282/restore-db2-database