# Restore DB2 database

Tags: linux, restore, db2

Is there anyway to restore a db2 database whose backup was made in Windows XP , to a linux machine ?
I am using the same version of db2 on both the OSes -> DB2 Express-C 9.7
Source OS : Windows XP SP2
Target OS : Ubuntu 9.04

Answer (score 8):

IBM has documentations for this scenario. See this page on DeveloperWorks: **[Using DB2 utilities to clone databases across different platforms](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0403melnyk/)**

> **Summary**:  Two DB2 utilities, db2move
>   and db2look, can be used to clone
>   databases when there is no support for
>   cross-platform backup and restore
>   operations. This article provides an
>   overview of these utilities and gives
>   a step-by-step example of how to clone
>   a DB2 database using this approach.

I've used already a similar procedure (involving db2move) to transfer a DB2 database from Windows to AIX and vice-versa.

> **Introduction**
>
> DB2’s native backup utility creates a backup image that is not portable from W2K to AIX or back.  This document presents the procedures required for moving any DB2 database from one platform to the other.
>
> **Assumptions**
>
> For purposes of example, this document assumes that the database to be ported from W2K (source platform) to AIX (target platform) is MYDB.
>
> **Procedure Details**
>
> Run the db2look command for MYDB database to generate the DDL for the MYDB database.
>
> `db2look -d mydb -e –l –x -o mydb_create.sql`
>
> Create a directory in which to store the logical backup of the source database MYDB.
>
> `mkdir backup`
>
> Change to the new directory, and create the logical backup using the db2move utility
>
> `cd backup`
>   `db2move mydb export`
>
> Transfer the backup of the database and DDL script from Source to Destination.  Transfer mydb_create.sql in ASCII mode, and all backup*.ixf files in binary mode.
>
> **The following steps are to be performed on the target platform.**
>
> Split the mydb_create.sql script into two scripts.  The first is named mydb_tables.sql, and should contain all alias, table, and view creation commands.  The second script is to be named mydb_ri.sql, and picks up where the first stopped, including check and foreign key constraints and grants.  Make sure that both scripts have a CONNECT command at the top, and COMMIT, CONNECT RESET, and TERMINATE commands at the end.
>
> Edit the mydb_tables.sql and ensure that any user tablespaces use only relative path names.  If absolute path names are used, the database cannot be restored multiple times on the same system without a REDIRECTED RESTORE.
>
> Create an empty MYDB database.
>
> `create db mydb`
>
> Run the mydb_tables.sql script to create aliases, tables, and views.
>
> `db2 –tvf mydb_tables.sql > mydb_tables.out`
>
> Review mydb_tables.out for errors.  An easy method of doing this is to run the following command.
>
> `grep SQL0 mydb_tables.out|grep –v SQL0403W|grep –v SQL0598W|more`
>
> Import the data to the tables (the INSERT option can be used instead of REPLACE, but REPLACE is rerunnable).
>
> `db2move mydb load -lo replace`
>
> Run the mydb_ri.sql script to create referential integrity constraints, etc.
>
> `db2 –tvf mydb_ri.sql > mydb_ri.out`
>
> Review mydb_ri.out for errors.  An easy method of doing this is to run the following command.
>
> `grep SQL0 mydb_ri.out|grep –v SQL0403W|grep –v SQL0598W|more`
>
> Verify that the source and target databases are identical.

Comment: Would this work for tables with IDENTITY GENERATED ALWAYS columns ?

Comment: pff can't remember for sure, I haven't "played" with DB2 for years, sorry.

Comment: Special care is needed for IDENTITY GENERATED ALWAYS columns as specified in this IBM article : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0205pilaka/0205pilaka2.html